# Multiple population returns me just empty Object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

#### MessageModel

This is the MessageSchema.

```
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    sender: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    content: { type: String, trim: true },
    chat: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Chat",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

### UserModel

This is UserSchema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    pic: {
      type: String,
      default:
        "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

This is How I try to populate but it doesn't work Its shows 404 Error instead. The thing is that if i removed the await message.populate("chat") everything starts working fine But i dont get the desired result

```
const sendMessage = async (req, res) => {
  const { content, chatId } = req.body;
  if (!content || !chatId) {
    console.log("Invalid data passed into request");
    res.status(400).send("Invalid Data");
  }

  var newMessage = {
    sender: req.user._id,
    content: content,
    chat: chatId,
  };

  try {
    var message = await MessageModel.create(newMessage);

    await message.populate("sender", "name pic");

     await message.populate("chat");

    await UserModel.populate(message, {
      path: "chat.users",
      select: "name pic email",
    });

    await ChatModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.chatId, {
      latestMessage: message,
    });

    res.send(message);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
};
```